# Apache Camel doneFileName

Tags: java, apache-camel

How can I use a reverse feature of `doneFileName` in `apache camel`.
If `doneFileName=somefile` is set in uri the component will wait for this some file to appear in order to process.
I need to check if a file `(ex: someFile)` exists then do nothing otherwise process files

Answer (score 2):

Use a filter and implement the logic (by extending `GenericFileFilter`) to check if that file exists or not, and then return `true` or `false` accordingly.

See the filter option in the file documentation at

- http://camel.apache.org/file2